# Event Delegation help, how can I ONLY target the <img> tags using Pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning event delegation, and I put the click event on the main parent, which is thumbnails. When I click on an image on the bottom, I want to set the src to the img class="main" src, but I noticed that when I click between the images, click anywhere else on the the thumbnails div, or press tab then enter I get null. I looked into it and found that my event.target is targeting the anchor tags, as well as the div class "thumbnails". I understand why, as I put the click event ON the thumbnails (parent), but is there a way I can only target the img tags?

Please no jQuery, I want to learn this using pure js, thanks!

```js
function displaySelected() {
  const getMainClass = document.querySelector('.main');
  const getThumbnails = document.querySelector('.thumbnails');

  getThumbnails.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    getMainClass.setAttribute('src', event.target.getAttribute('src'));
    console.log(event.target);
  });
}

displaySelected();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.hero {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.hero img {
  height: 100%
}


.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 60px;
}

a.thumbnail:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
}

.thumbnail img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <main role="main">
    <h1>Image Carousel</h1>
    <div class="hero">
      <img class="main" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-65/cat1.jpg" alt="An orange-eyed grey cat stretches toward the camera."/>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnails">
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-65/cat1.jpg" alt="An orange-eyed grey cat stretches toward the camera."/></a>
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-65/cat2.jpg" alt="Closeup of a blue-eyed, grey cat with markings."/></a>
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-65/cat3.jpg" alt="An orange cat licks its paw."/></a>
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-65/cat4.jpg" alt="A content brown cat lounges with eyes closed."/></a>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are adding the `event listener` every time the `function` is called. You should only add the `event listener` once.
2. Check the `tagName` to see if the `target` is an `IMG` and if so, set the `src`, else do nothing

```js
//Add the event listener once the DOM loads
const getThumbnails = document.querySelector('.thumbnails');
getThumbnails.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    displaySelected(event);
});


//Check if the event target has tagName of IMG
function displaySelected(event) {
    if(event.target.tagName === "IMG"){
        const getMainClass = document.querySelector('img.main');
        getMainClass.src = event.target.getAttribute('src');
    }
}
```

```css
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.hero {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.hero img {
  height: 100%
}


.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 60px;
}

a.thumbnail:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
}

.thumbnail img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <main role="main">
    <h1>Image Carousel</h1>
    <div class="hero">
      <img class="main" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-65/cat1.jpg" alt="An orange-eyed grey cat stretches toward the camera."/>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnails">
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-65/cat1.jpg" alt="An orange-eyed grey cat stretches toward the camera."/></a>
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-65/cat2.jpg" alt="Closeup of a blue-eyed, grey cat with markings."/></a>
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-65/cat3.jpg" alt="An orange cat licks its paw."/></a>
      <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-65/cat4.jpg" alt="A content brown cat lounges with eyes closed."/></a>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```